# Jquery DataTables Two Fields in One Column using IF statement

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable using AJAX.  I would like to have two fields together in one column and also use if statements for both fields.

I can do two fields together:

```
  { 
     "data" : function (data, type, dataToSet) {return data.primary + "<br/>" + data.proctor;
   }},
```

I have added some styling a based off an if statement:

```
    {
      "data" : "primary",
      "render" : function(primary) {
          if (!primary) {
                return '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> primary';
          } else {
                 return '<i style="color: green" class="fa fa-check"></i> primary';
                    }
                }
            },
   {
      "data": "proctor",
      "render": function (proctor) {
          if (!primary) {
                 return '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> proctor';
          } else {
                 return '<i style="color: green" class="fa fa-check"></i> proctor';
                    }
                }
            },
```

How would I combine the two fields into one column and still have the if/else statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two fields by adding a `null` column with its own `render` method :

```
columns: [
  ...
  { data: null,
    render: function(data, type, full) {
      var ret = '';
      if (!full.primary) {
        ret += '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> primary';
      } else {
        ret += '<i style="color: green" class="fa fa-check"></i> primary';
      }
      if (!full.proctor) {
        ret += '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> proctor';
      } else {
        ret += '<i style="color: green" class="fa fa-check"></i> proctor';
      }
      return ret;
    }
  }
]
```

BTW: I think that ternarys in this case would be better than `if..else`. At least more readable :

```
var ret = !full.primary
   ? '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> primary'
   : '<i style="color: green" class="fa fa-check"></i> primary';

ret += !full.proctor
   ? '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> proctor'
   : '<i style="color: green" class="fa fa-check"></i> proctor';

return ret;
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  I agree the ternarys are more readable.  Thanks for providing both examples.